# Linux server Cpu,memory,swap,run que value to display in percentage

Tags: linux, memory

how to write a script to get a linux server below details:

```
CPU                    |Memory                  |Swap                   |Run Queue  
Peak(%) Relative Avg(%)|Peak(%) Relative Avg(%) |Peak(K),Relative Avg(K)|Peak,Relative Avg%
```

Comment: That i have checked, top,sar to see the details.but issue is with to display it in percentage. any link or info which can be referred to make this report ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to extract the data with Sar if you are looking to create reports and logs yourself. A nice real time tool is htop, in case you need it

Comment: That i have checked, top,sar to see the details.but issue is with to display it in percentage. any link or info which can be referred to make this report ?

Comment: @user91227 I noticed your post didn't receive any other response and it's probably a bit late but for future reference, you can write your script to use the commands  expr and/or bc to do match calculations